# Retrieve only the records that have the MAX DateCreated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, max

I have a large query that returns several records. I need to pull only the records that have the most recent Date Created from it. I have tried using a subquery and ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY and can't figure it out.

For example if my query returns 100 records and only 5 of them have the most recent date then my final query should only be returning those 5 records.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName, c.DateCreated ORDER BY c.DateCreated Desc, COUNT(*) Desc) AS rn, DateCreated
FROM  Customer As c   
WHERE c.Field1 = @Param1 and c.Field2= @Param2
```

In this case I normally would just do WHERE rn = 1.... But my result has groupings for each different DateCreated so the 'rn' column goes something like 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4

Comment: I updated it with my query sorry.

Comment: By most recent date do you mean for the entire table or for each partition?

Answer (score 1):

Remove date from partition. You want to work within one customer and pick latest date. Also I dont know exactly, but consider removing `count(*)` from `order by` clause:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName ORDER BY c.DateCreated Desc, COUNT(*) Desc) AS rn, DateCreated
FROM  Customer As c   
WHERE c.Field1 = @Param1 and c.Field2= @Param2
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the date from the partition; it's returning a row for every customer/date combination like you described. Try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName ORDER BY c.DateCreated Desc) AS rn, 
    DateCreated
FROM  Customer As c   
WHERE c.Field1 = @Param1 and c.Field2= @Param2
)

SELECT
*
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```